# unit testing vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, tdd

In my vue component I am have a some methods firing off in the mounted lifecycle,

```
mounted() {
    this.GET_WORKFLOW_TYPES()
      .then(() => {
        this.GET_WORKFLOW_EVENTS_BY_TYPE({workflow_type: this.audit.selectedWorkflowType})
      });
  },
```

The above are actions in my store and they are mapped into my component like the following,

```
methods: {
   ...mapActions([ACTION_TYPES.GET_WORKFLOW_TYPES, ACTION_TYPES.GET_WORKFLOW_EVENTS_BY_TYPE]);
}
```

I am wanting to test that both these functions get called in my unit test so I have tried,

```
it('Should render the audit component and it\'s children', async () => {
        wrapper = mount(AdminAudit, { store, localVue});
        //Does it retrieve the data we need
        expect(actions.GET_WORKFLOW_TYPES).toHaveBeenCalled();
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {  
            expect(actions.GET_WORKFLOW_EVENTS_BY_TYPE).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
})
```

but i get the following response,

> console.error ../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1893
> JestAssertionError: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

How do I go about testing chained async calls?

For reference we are using vue version 2.6.14

Answer (score 0):

The Vuex actions are scheduled on microtasks *after* the component has mounted, but your first assertion is run before the first action has resolved.

One solution is to wait until the *next* micro tick:

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { store, localVue })

await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() 
expect(actions[ACTION_TYPES.GET_WORKFLOW_TYPES]).toHaveBeenCalled()
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() 
expect(actions[ACTION_TYPES.GET_WORKFLOW_EVENTS_BY_TYPE]).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Alternatively, you could wait until the next *macro* tick at which point the current micro tasks would've already completed:

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { store, localVue })
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r)) 

expect(actions[ACTION_TYPES.GET_WORKFLOW_TYPES]).toHaveBeenCalled()
expect(actions[ACTION_TYPES.GET_WORKFLOW_EVENTS_BY_TYPE]).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-jest-test-vuex-mapaction?file=tests%2Funit%2FMyComponent.spec.js)